# Random crashing when reading file using fscanf/fgets at different iterations

Tags: c, file, file-io

I am trying to read from the while questions.txt which has the following format:

```
Question\n
Difficulty:Cost:Prize\n
Correct Answer\n
Answer 1\n
.
.
.
Answer i\n
\n
```

The following is a function that reads from questions.txt and stores it to a temporary node to be added to a linked list.

```
pQuestionType loadQuestions(pQuestionType pFirst)
{
    pQuestionType pTemp = malloc(sizeof(pQuestionType));
    FILE* pFile;
    string sFilename, sTemp;
    char cDump;
    int nTemp, n=0;
    gotoxy(0,0);
    system("cls");
    printf("Enter file name: ");
    gets(sFilename);
    pFile = fopen(sFilename, "rt");
    while(!feof(pFile))
    {
        printf("Iteration \n");
        fgets(sTemp, 255, pFile);
        strcpy(pTemp->sQuestion, sTemp);
        pTemp->sQuestion[strlen(sTemp)-1] = '\0';
        printf("Add question success\n");

        fscanf(pFile, "%d%c", &nTemp, &cDump);
        pTemp->nDifficulty = nTemp;
        printf("Add difficulty success\n");

        fscanf(pFile, "%d%c", &nTemp, &cDump);
        pTemp->nCost = nTemp;
        printf("Add cost success\n");

        fscanf(pFile, "%d%c", &nTemp, &cDump);
        pTemp->nWinnings = nTemp;
        printf("Add winnings success\n");

        fgets(sTemp, 255, pFile);
        strcpy(pTemp->sCorrect, sTemp);
        pTemp->sCorrect[strlen(sTemp)-1] = '\0';
        strcpy(pTemp->sAnswers[0], sTemp);
        pTemp->sAnswers[0][strlen(sTemp)-1] = '\0';
        printf("Add answer success\n");

        for(n=1; n<10; n++)
        {
            fgets(sTemp, 255, pFile);
            if(*sTemp == '\n')break;
            strcpy(pTemp->sAnswers[n], sTemp);
            pTemp->sAnswers[n][strlen(sTemp)-1] = '\0'; 
        }
        printf("Add choices success\n");

        printf("\n");   
        pFirst = addQuestion(pFirst, pTemp);        
        if(*sTemp == EOF) break;
    }
    fclose(pFile);

    return pFirst;
}
```

I crash at the third iteration when the program tries to read the difficulty of my third question. What causes this and what can I do to fix my code?

Comment: What line does your debugger leave you at when you crash, and what are the values of the relevant data elements at that point?

Comment: 1) Seeing the fixed buffer sizes in the structure format you chose *not* to show is probably key to your crash. 2) LRN2DBG.

Comment: 1) `pTemp->sQuestion[strlen(sTemp)-1] = '\0';` will do nasty things if strlen() happens to be zero. 2) feof() is always wrong 3) does your struct contain pointers? 4) check the return value from sscanf() 5) maybe check the character in cDump, too. 6) diagnostic output should go to stderr. 7) ` if(*sTemp == EOF)` You are comparing a character and an int here.

Comment: 9) `string` is not a C data type. What is it? 10) gets() is an unsafe function, especially when given unknown data types as an argument. 10) gotoxy() is a non standard function. 11) Bingo!

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for the points you raised, my function is a whole lot better now~ also, string is a typedef'd char[255]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pQuestionType pTemp = malloc(sizeof(pQuestionType));
```

If `pQuestionType` is a *pointer* type (and it appears to be since neither `pFirst` nor `pTemp` have a `*` character anywhere near their declaration), then its size is going to be the size of a pointer (currently likely to be 4 or 8).

So this `malloc` will almost certainly not give you enough memory. You need to use `sizeof(*pTemp)` instead.

Comment: +1: I sure hope it is a pointer-type, since it is **repeatedly** passed to `addQuestion()` after only a single allocation (wtf?) Furthermore, are we holding bets that `sAnswers[]` is an uninitialized pointer array in that struct type? =P

Comment: yes, it is a pointer-type and yeah, sAnswers is an uninitialized in the struct type...

Comment: @user1887849 the type information of QuestionType would lend a LOT to how horked up this code is, as well as a peek at `addQuestion()` Consider posting a little more relevant info with your next question. (just a little).

Comment: Okay it works now! \:D/ Transferred the malloc within the loop instead of outside of it and changed the size to QuestionTag. Thanks all~